# Can't Login To MySQL After Changing Password

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set a user's password but after I set it, I still can't log in as that user.

```
$ mysql -uroot -p mydb
Enter password:

mysql> select user,host,password from mysql.user;
...
webapp | % | *.... |

mysql> show grants for webapp@'%';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'webapp'@'%' IDNETIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...'
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON 'mydb'.* TO 'webapp'@'%'

mysql> set password for webapp@'%'=PASSWORD('mypassword');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit

$ mysql -uwebapp -p mydb
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'webapp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I just set the password and it does not work, what is happening?

By the way the user's table only has one entry with the name 'webapp' and its host is '%'

I'm using mysql 5.1.67.  I also tried restarting mysqld, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @msknapp, Does the old password still work? Did you `flush privileges`?

Comment: flushing privileges did not change anything.  I don't know the old password, which is why I'm trying to change it.  I'm going to update the question to show flush privileges

Comment: Try it like this: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON 'your_database_name_here'.* TO 'your_username_here'@'%' IDNETIFIED BY 'your_password_here'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` each command on its own line. There is no need to reset password after these 2 commands.

Comment: @msknapp let us know if that worked.

Comment: @Prix, I just tried your advice, sorry, it's still not working.

Comment: could this somehow be related to the host name?  MySQL tries logging me in under 'localhost', and the db has only one row in the user table for 'webapp' and its host is '%'

Comment: @msknapp I suspect you might have other entries for the same user, try this: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON 'your_database_name_here'.* TO 'your_username_here'@'localhost' IDNETIFIED BY 'your_password_here'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: @msknapp yes it could if you have more than 1 user in the users table of the mysql database

Comment: there is only one entry in the user table for that user, shouldn't mysql decide that it matches?  Could this be a bug in the version I'm using?

Comment: @msknapp `The server uses the first row that matches the client host name and user name.`

Comment: like I said there is only one row, is it possible that mysql does not think '%' matches 'localhost'?

Comment: **What do you get with** `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'webapp';` just to make sure. `%` it should think it matches as it is a wildcard.

Comment: that's exactly what I did, that's how I concluded there is only one row for that user in the user table.

Comment: `mysql -u webapp -p -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP` does this give you the same outcome? is skip-networking on or off?

Comment: yes, same outcome.  skip-networking is off

Comment: [Well that's why most likely. What I believe that is happening is that your mysql is listening to the socket only which is why `%` does not work so you will need to use a grant with `localhost` unless you change networking.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking)

Comment: If the GRANT with localhost works then we have 2 definitive answer, 1) localhost does make difference in some specific setup 2) networkign is not running

Comment: @Prix, you were right, that fixed it.  I never knew about the skip-networking variable.  Put this in an answer and I will mark it right.

Comment: @msknapp just to make sure before I put the answer you turned skip-networking to ON and its working right? Without having to add the localhost user.

Comment: actually I left skip-networking off and performed the grant statement you gave me earlier with localhost as the host.  If you want me to remove that and try with skip-networking I can.

Comment: @msknapp you will have to remove the user name with localhost as well to make sure that was the case. I will put both in my answer just in case.

Comment: hmm that is strange, I did "delete from mysql.user where user='webapp' and host='localhost';" and verified that the line was removed from the user table.  Then I tried logging again, and it worked when I really expected it to fail.

Comment: @msknapp `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`?

Comment: right again, how could I forget that, OMG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the tests we've done on the comments the issue you're having is that you have `skip-networking` on your server which makes it not listen to TCP/IP connections at all.

Since its not listening to the TCP/IP connections your MySQL server is using the socket to connect hence you need to have a user entry that contains `localhost` as the socket uses `localhost`.

As you have tested, adding the `localhost` granted use fixed the issue and it also defines the fact that it does make a difference whether you do have or not a user with `localhost` for this sort of specific server configurations for example.

In your case the command run to accomplish the `localhost` granted use was:

```
        GRANT SELECT, 
              INSERT, 
              UPDATE, 
              DELETE, 
              EXECUTE 
           ON 'your_database_name_here'.* 
           TO 'your_username_here'@'localhost' 
IDNETIFIED BY 'your_password_here';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Just as further reference:

> skip-networking : Don’t listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets. This option is highly recommended for systems where only local requests are allowed. Since you need to allow remote connection this line should be removed from my.cnf or put it in comment state.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking